# Ruby on Rails plugin - Adding validation in class doesn't work properly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-plugins

I made a small DRY plugin that I want to use in some of my classes (like theatre, coffeeshop, restaurant, etc) later on. All those classes consist of an address and therefore, I made an Address model plugin with an *act_as_address* method that are to be called by those classes to avoid writing duplicate code.

The classes will consist of some validations on the address fields (like presence and length) and I used *class_eval* inside the *act_as_address* in the Address model to write those validations to the classes. However, it does not seem to work.

Here is my code and tests:

```
# structure.sql
create table addresses (
  some_info varchar(25)
  # other attrs
);

create table theatres (
  id integer,
  primary key (id)
) inherits (addresses);


# act_as_address.rb
module Address
  module ActsAsAddress
    extend ActiveSupport::Concern

    include do
    end

    module ClassMethods
      def acts_as_address
        class_eval do <<-EVAL
        validates :some_info, presence: true
        # some other validations, methods etc.
        EVAL
        end
      end
    end
  end
end

ActiveRecord::Base.send :include, Address::ActsAsAddress

# theatre.rb
class Theatre < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_address
end

# address.rb
require 'address/acts_as_address'

module Address
end

# acts_as_address_test.rb
require File.expand_path('../test_helper', __FILE__)

class ActsAsAddressTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  test "should not be valid" do
    assert_not Theatre.create(:some_info => nil).valid?, 
      "some_info was valid with nil value"
  end
end
```

And the result of the test is as following:

```
  1) Failure:
ActsAsAddressTest#test_should_not_be_valid [acts_as_address_test.rb:16]:
some_info was valid with nil value
```

Could anyone help me out here? Is *class_eval* the problem here? I am using Ruby on Rails 4.

Comment: Why do you need the class_eval at all? Will you be dynamically generating code?

Comment: Like I stated in my post, because I will have more classes like Theatre: like Coffeeshop, Restaurant etc. My idea is to write act_as_addresses in those classes to not having to put the address validations in there (to stay DRY).

Comment: OK but I still don't think that needs class_eval. validates is just a class method that has already been defined. You just need to pass the right arguments (i.e. column name(s) and specific validations) to it.

class_eval would only be needed if you want to define a whole new method (and even then there are better ways to do it).

Comment: Did this approach work for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may be able to do this:

```
module Address
  module ActsAsAddress
    extend ActiveSupport::Concern

    module ClassMethods
      def acts_as_address
        validates :some_info, presence: true
      end
    end
  end
end
```